# Java: Adding 45 days to a DateTime object using joda-time produces a nonsensical date

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to manipulate dates in joda-time. I simply want to go 45 days into the future.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, MMMM D, yyyy");
DateTime endDate = startDate.plusDays(45);
System.out.println(fmt.print(endDate));
```

My output is

```
Saturday, February 46, 2014.
```

Obviously, February 46 is not a real date.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a simple way to get the correct date in joda-time?
2. If not, am I misunderstanding the purpose of joda-time? I thought it was designed to easily handle these kinds of calculations. Am I better off using another library if I want to add/subtract days to dates?

Comment: Always test your formatter by calling the DateTime object's `toString` method (rendering an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string) to compare results.

Comment: If the question is answered, don't edit the title with `(ANSWERED)`, actually check the green check mark under the helpful answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

D is day of year, ie, numbers of days since January 1st.

d is day of month. So your date format would be:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");
```